# php regex match: contains and ends with

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of files that look like that:

> dispatcher.frontFailedLogs

I would like a regex that matches file names according to these requirements:

> filename contains "FailedLogs"
>
> filename ends with "log"

so I can use it like this:

```
$failedLogsFiles = preg_grep('~.log$~', scandir($logDir));
```

Comment: `/FailedLogs.*log$/`?

Comment: Nop, doesnt work in the preg_grep context...

Comment: Are your requirements OR-connected? /(FailedLogs|log$)/

Comment: AND. All of them should hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.*` to include every thing between:

```
preg_grep('@.*FailedLogs.*\.log$@', scandir($logDir));
```